# Doctrine Composite Keys Throwing Error

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I am trying to update my schema in doctrine using:

```
php vendor/bin/doctrine orm:schema-tool:update
```

But I am getting the error message:

```
[Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException]                                      
  Single id is not allowed on composite primary key in entity entities\Events
```

The events entity looks like this:

```
<?php
// entities/Events.php

namespace entities;

use Entities\Enities;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Table;

/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="development.events")
 **/
class Events extends Entities {
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @Id
     * @Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $event_id;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @Id
     * @Column(name="app_id", type="integer")
     */
    protected $app_id = 0;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @Column(type="string", length=64)
     */
    protected $post_title;

    public function __construct($event, $app){
        $this->event_id = $event;
        $this->app_id= $app;
    }

}
```

According to documentation, composite keys are natively supported. http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/composite-primary-keys.html What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

From the docs:

> Every entity with a composite key cannot use an id generator other than “ASSIGNED”. That means the ID fields have to have their values set before you call EntityManager#persist($entity).

So remove `@GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")`.

Comment: It worked, but does that mean that for that value I have to great and ID or UUID programatically instead of having the database create the auto incremented value?

Comment: Yes, or you can use [#identity-through-foreign-entities](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/composite-primary-keys.html#identity-through-foreign-entities), but I don't really get what is your use case and what do you want to achieve? Using composite keys not recommended and you should avoid it when possible.