# Single ID is not allowed on composite primary key in entity

Tags: symfony, symfony-3.4, api-platform.com

I'm creating an API REST using the API Platform framework. I have an entity with a composite primary key.

I'm getting this error when sending a get request on the table `Umlfiles_Properties`:

> Single id is not allowed on composite primary key in entity AppBundle\Entity\Umlfiles_Properties

The code bellow is the `Umlfiles_Properties` entity code.

```
/**
* Umlfiles_Properties
*
* @ApiResource
* @ORM\Table(name="umlfiles_properties")
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\Umlfiles_PropertiesRepository")
*/
class Umlfiles_Properties
{
/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="umlfile_id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Umlfiles", inversedBy="id")
 */
private $umlfile_id;

/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="property_id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Property", inversedBy="id")
 */
private $property_id;

/**
 * @var array
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="value", type="array")
 */
private $value;



/**
 * Set umlfileId.
 *
 * @param int $umlfileId
 *
 * @return Umlfiles_Properties
 */
public function setUmlfileId($umlfileId)
{
    $this->umlfile_id = $umlfileId;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get umlfileId.
 *
 * @return int
 */
public function getUmlfileId()
{
    return $this->umlfile_id;
}

/**
 * Set propertyId.
 *
 * @param int $propertyId
 *
 * @return Umlfiles_Properties
 */
public function setPropertyId($propertyId)
{
    $this->property_id = $propertyId;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get propertyId.
 *
 * @return int
 */
public function getPropertyId()
{
    return $this->property_id;
}

/**
 * Set value.
 *
 * @param array $value
 *
 * @return Umlfiles_Properties
 */
public function setValue($value)
{
    $this->value = $value;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get value.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function getValue()
{
    return $this->value;
}
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Doctrine Composite Keys Throwing Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36017864/doctrine-composite-keys-throwing-error)

Comment: This might be API Platform not handling composite keys correctly and invoking Doctrine incorrectly as a result.

Comment: Any update on this issue?